# How to enable mouse focus in Linux Mint 15 with Cinnamon

Tags: linux, mouse, linux-mint, system-preferences, window-focus

I'm a big fan of mouse-focus, or "focus follows mouse", and I had this enabled in Mint 14, but when I reinstalled with Mint 15 I can't find the option anywhere. None of the sections in "system settings" has this option, and none of the options under the "preferences" section of the main menu seem relevant. Google yields some forum posts for older Mint versions, and often include hacking around in gconf setting manually. Is there a straight-forward way to enable this in Cinnamon on Mint 15?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Open the settings app (run `cinnamon-settings`) from a terminal or use the menu.

   [image]
2. If you have not done so already, switch to "Advanced Mode"

   [image]
3. Type focus in the search field at the top

   [image]
4. That brings up the "Windows" section, click on it, then select "mouse" from the "Windows focus mode" menu.

   [image]

Comment: Ok, so the problem was, I wasn't seeing the "window" section in the settings manager, but I just noticed the "Switch to advanced mode" button at the bottom and then it shows up. If you want to add that step to your answer I'll accept it. :)

Comment: @IsaacFreeman ah, sorry, I had already switched, answer modified.

Comment: For later versions of Cinnamon, searching the settings for ¨focus¨ will reveal the option you want.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded-to by commenter Michael Scheper, there is no “Advanced Mode” in recent releases (July, ‘23); relevant settings are in the “Windows” widget.

Comment: You could improve your answer by attaching a screenshot.